# iOS Push notifications with passbook

Tags: php, json, apple-push-notifications

I'm currently writing a passbook API that allows users to send push notifications to passes. Now I'm at the point of testing it but my push notification aren't arriving. I'm writing the push sending code in PHP and this is what I have so far:

```
$payload = json_encode(array("aps" => array("alert" => "test", "sound" => "default")));
//send it to all devices found
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
{
    error_log($row['pushToken']);
    //write the push message to the apns socket connection
    $msg = chr(0) .
    pack("n",32) .
    pack('H*', $row['pushToken']) .
    pack("n",strlen($payload)) .
    $payload;
    fwrite($fp, $msg);
}
```

Is there anything I'm missing here or doing wrong? The certificate is valid and connecting to the APNS server doesn't give me any error.

Thanks!

Comment: do you have the correct token? they differ for develop and production servers...

Comment: I thought that the sandbox server doesn't support passbook push notifications, so I'm using the production server ;)

Comment: ok, I thought it did support it... nevermind, at least you have the right token :)

Comment: what error are you getting ? have you check error_log ??

Comment: I'm getting no error in error_log and it can connect to the APNS server. Is there any way I can get feedback from the APNS servers to see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Where $payload goes in above code ?

Comment: $payload is being send to the APNS server isn't it?

Comment: can you paste whole code snippet ? because current snippet code doesn't helping to debug your issue ?

Comment: You mean my whole push sending method? I doubt it's going wrong there because it can connect to the APNS server. One line below the code in my post, I close the connection to the APNS server and that's all ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this problem by re-creating the certificate, doing the openssl magic again and use the new certicates. Now it's working, so I think there was something bugged in my certificate :)

Comment: Please provide the exact steps when creating the new certificate for APNS. This is your Pass Type ID certificate, right?

Comment: yeah the answer you gave is too vague and only helpful for you. We would like to know how to exactly do this 'ssl magic'

Comment: I followed this tutorial which describes in-depth how to create passes and sign them: http://www.raywenderlich.com/20734/beginning-passbook-part-1 (also part two is on the site)